# Tesseract fails to recognize digits, even with rescaling, char white_listing and filtering

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

For an open source [pokerbot](https://github.com/dickreuter/Poker) I'm trying to recognize images as implemented [here](https://github.com/dickreuter/Poker/blob/master/poker/scraper/screen_operations.py#L64). I have tried the following with an example image that I'd like tesseract to recognize:

[image]

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_orig)
Out[32]: 'cies TE'

pytesseract.image_to_string(img_mod, 'eng', config='--psm 6 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.$£B')
Out[33]: ''
```

So then let's use some more sophisticated methods by scaling::

```
basewidth = 200
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img_orig.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img_orig.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img_resized = img_orig.convert('L').resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
if binarize:
    img_resized = binarize_array(img_resized, 200)
```

Now we end up with an image looking like this:

[image]

Let's see what comes out:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_resized)
Out[34]: 'Stee'

pytesseract.image_to_string(img_resized, 'eng', config='--psm 6 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.$£B')
Out[35]: ''
```

Ok, that didn't work. Let's try applying some filers:

```
img_min = img_resized.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter)
img_mod = img_resized.filter(ImageFilter.ModeFilter)
img_med = img_resized.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter)
img_sharp = img_resized.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)

pytesseract.image_to_string(img_min)
Out[36]: ''
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_mod)
Out[37]: 'oe Se'
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_med)
Out[38]: 'rete'
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_sharp)
Out[39]: 'ry'
```

Or maybe binarize will help?

```
numpy_array = np.array(image)
for i in range(len(numpy_array)):
    for j in range(len(numpy_array[0])):
        if numpy_array[i][j] > threshold:
            numpy_array[i][j] = 255
        else:
            numpy_array[i][j] = 0
img_binarized = Image.fromarray(numpy_array)

pytesseract.image_to_string(img_binarized)
Out[42]: 'Sion'
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_binarized, 'eng', config='--psm 6 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.$£B')
Out[44]: '0'
```

Again, all totally wrong.
What else can I do? 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Add on example:

[image]

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
im_pil = cv2_to_pil(threshold_img)

pytesseract.image_to_string(im_pil)
Out[5]: 'TUM'
```

or trying another suggested algo for:

[image]

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
im_pil = cv2_to_pil(threshold_img)
pytesseract.image_to_string(im_pil, 'eng', config='--psm 7')
Out[5]: '$1.99'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it too complicated here. I did simple Otsu thresholding on the image that you've provided and was able to get the output.

```
image_path = r'path/to/image'
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
detected_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_path))
print(detected_text)
```

The image that I got after thresholding was
 [image]
Tesseract was easily able to detect it and the output I got: `$0.51`

Comment: It indeed happens to work with this example But not with the next best (added to original question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with or without Otsu. The trick for me was to invert the image so that it's black text on white background (which Tesseract seems to prefer).

**EDIT** One more trick for Tesseract is to add a border around the image. Tesseract does not like for the text to be too close to the edge.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('one_twenty_nine.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  

thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
detected_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config = '--psm 7')
print(detected_text)
```

which gives

```
$1.29
```

Comment: I like the approach but it doesn't seem to do the trick either. Added another example